# New NavigationView starts from second item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I really don't know why but using the new `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` i've got an issue. I'm able to create the correct drawer with the fragments is need and in my drawer_menu.xml i have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/main_item"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_main"
            android:title="@string/main"
            />
        <item
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/second_item"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_playlist_add_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/app_list"
            />

    </group>
</menu>
```

here's the java part of the menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        @IdRes int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        if(id == mCurrentMenuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
        switch (id){
            case R.id.main_item:
                setNewRootFragment(MainFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case R.id.second_item:
                setNewRootFragment(SecondFragment.newInstance());
                break;
        }
        mCurrentMenuItem = id;
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        return false;
    }
```

When the application starts the Fragment i see for first it's correct but in the list of the drawer is selected the second one. How is possible?

Comment: as ianhanniballake answer you have set checked='true' make it false or remove that line ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `android:checked="true"` on the second item in your list. Move that to the first item if you'd like it to appear selected at first.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was on the code from many many hours and I haven't seen that. Thank you!